# Can any function of two variables be expressed as a linear combination?

Tags: analysis

Can any function of two variables be expressed as a linear combination (may be infinite) of a product of two single-variable functions?

$f(x,y) = \sum A_n g_n(x) h_n(y)$

Comment: You should lookup Taylor's formula in two variables.

Comment: I believe there is no general answer. See this MathOverflow question: [When is separation of variables an acceptable assumption to solve a PDE?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/175802)

Comment: @PierreCarre Not all functions are analytical somewhere.

Comment: @Eureka sure... I'm just saying that the statement can be proven correct for some class of functions.

Comment: It's true for at least continuous function (and I think for Borel functions too).